# Can one application with one server serve websockets and http traffic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, websocket, rack

Is this somehow possible? Is it possible to do something like this in Ruby on top of Rack? I've seen there's websockets-rack but as far as I understand, that is only a rack module to serve ONLY websocket traffic not http also.

So basically, as the question states, is it possible to serve both protocols with just one server on the same port, instead of firing of something like Faye, websockets-rack or em-websockets?

Comment: Is the requirement one server, or single port?

Comment: It would be one port, so basically that I can start one Ruby application that would serve both on the same port.

Comment: And having two servers serving one port - would that be an option?

Comment: That would require some lower level hacks, wouldn't it? My question would actually be is there a possibility to have one server on one port route all the traffic to the app, and then the app could decide what it's going to do with it. I'm not sure if that is even possible, for a server to serve both http and ws. Kinda confused, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Websockets are just an in-protocol upgrade of HTTP(s), so they are not normal TCP sockets but reuse the existing HTTP(S) connection (and thus use the same port). So, in theory it should work and from what I know it works with the Perl Mojolicious framework. But I don't know if it works work ruby/rack.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - (AFAIK) no.

Currently, a ruby HTTP server (like rails or sinatra) and a websocket server are mutually exclusive.

After saying that, you *could* use a third party to emulate that. Specifically [`Ngnix`](http://nginx.com/). With `Nginx` you can listen to a single port, but, accroding to a path, decide whether you want to dispatch the request to the HTTP server or the Websocket server.

For example, you can run the HTTP server on port 3000, and the Websocket server on port 3020, and then configure the `nginx.conf` like this:

```
upstream http_app {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream websocket_app {
  server 127.0.0.1:3020;
}
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name .example.com;

  access_log /var/www/myapp.example.com/log/access.log;
  error_log  /var/www/myapp.example.com/log/error.log;
  root     /var/www/myapp.example.com;
  index    index.html;

  location /web {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    proxy_pass http://http_app;
  }

  location /socket {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    proxy_pass http://websocket_app;
  }
}
```

Now any request to `http://www.example.com/web/...` will reach the HTTP server, and any request to `http://www.example.com/socket` will reach the Websocket server.

Comment: -1: How can websocket server and http be mutually exclusive if websocket is just an extension of http? The only thing that stops a websocket server to be an http server (and vice versa) is that the technology is not mature yet. Plus you are contradicting yourself, since you've given an example of nginx which can handle both http and websockets at the same time.

Comment: I was vague in my answer, that I was talking about _ruby_ solutions (rails and sinatra), and using nginx's power as a proxy to serve two containers which are currently incompatible. I've added a clarification that I'm talking about ruby.

Comment: Fair enough, I've removed -1.